# See if the events queue is empty with GLFW3

Tags: events, glfw

I want to see if the event queue is empty with GLFW3. Before, I used SDL2 and SDL_PollEvent return a value to show it but glfwPollEvent ( it equivalent ) doesn't return any value and I didn't find any functions that can show me this.

Comment: This functionality doesn't exist in GLFW 3 but I'm making a note of this for GLFW 4.

Comment: Yeah, I just see this when I compared the source code of GLFW and SDL.